# How do I target everything except for 1 element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a href which opens a photo in the middle of the screen (think of it like fancybox/lightbox/lytebox), which I want to close when the user clicks anywhere on the site, except for the div with the photo.

How can I target this with jQuery?

Comment: This is typically done with an overlay div with a z-index less than the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the jQuery `.not()` method.

```
$(".elements").not(".this-element").on("click", function() {
  $(".this-element").hide();
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6McAF/

**Update**

As [@nnnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615754/nnnnnn) has pointed out, you run into some complicated propagation issues when you do this. A better way is to use an overlay div (with a z-index less than the element you are wanting to hide, as mentioned by [@j08691](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616443/j08691)), and bind to that.

Or add another handler (which I don't recommend):

```
$(".this-element").on("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); // ugly boilerplate to fix thoughtless bindings
);
```

Comment: This won't work if the element being excluded by `.not()` is a child of the element that the click handler is bound to, because the click event will propagate up from the child to the container. For that case you'd need to check the event target (or add a second handler to the child to `stopPropagation()`).